# hudson & bash commands using windows batch file - window 7

Tags: hudson

I am configuring Hudson on windows machine (window 7 64 bit & window 2008 machine) 
I have a batch file which call bash & shell scripts. This shell script call other shell scripts & so on. 
I configured hudson job to call my batch file myBatch.bat. MyBatch.bat file then using following code to call bash & shell scripts:

```
bash -u -o pipefail -c "./buildAll.ksh %BRANCH% %PREV_TAG% %NEXT_TAG% build-%NEXT_TAG%.log 2>&1 | tee "build-%NEXT_TAG%.log"
```

I am getting this error:

> 'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I have configured cygwin bin directory path in my PATH env variable. I restarted Hudson server. I am running hudson as java -jar Hudson.war

I am not able to execute that batch file.

Comment: Can you confirm if you can run the batch file from the command prompt? (not cygwin shell)

Comment: The error means the hudson user does not have the `bash` binary in its `PATH`. Try to add a Windows command build step that does `echo %PATH%`, that should reveal if your `PATH` change has affected the hudson-running user.